# Resize Infragistics UltraGrid to contents

Tags: winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

How do I resize the entire ultragrid control in code to only show its contents?

i.e: I have

```
-----------------------------
|   |   |    |    blank      |
|   |   |    |               |
|   |   |    |               |
| ------------               |
|                            |
|                            |
|____________________________|
```

and I want the borders to be tight to the grid

Comment: so you want the columns to autofit to the size of the grid?

Comment: No, I want the outer bit of grid to shrink to size of columns and rows. Probably super simple and I am over thinking it. Try again tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

My best bet so far was to query DefaultLayout.Bands(0).GetExtent() and use that as the width of the grid.

Comment: Cheers Prof ... I'm on another project now so will not be able to check your answer.